# formatting text in jdialog box

Tags: java, fonts, colors, awt

I have a JOptionPane:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text);
```

The text is a sting:

```
String text = "Hello world."
```

What I want to do is change the color of the text, specifically a single word, lets say 'Hello'. SO what I've tried is:

```
String t1 = "Hello";
String t2 = "world."
Font serifFont = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12);
AttributedString as = new AttributedString(t1);
as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, serifFont); 
as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.red);


JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, as+t2);
```

I'm not familiar with attributedtext() and this wont work. It does this:

"java.text.AttributedString@479c479cworld"

Is there a step I'm missing? Is this not the right way? Any suggestions?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be possible to use html to solve this, ie

```
String t = "<html><font color=#ffffdd>Hello</font> world!";
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html for more info.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working for me, still has the html markup in the dialog text.

Comment: I may not being doing this right so can you please elaborate. What if the sentence was: The quick brown fox.
And I wanted only "brown" to be the color brown?

Comment: Tried to no avail, i know the hex isn't for brown didn't have time to look it up:
String text = "The quick <html><font color=#ffffdd>brown</font> fox."

Comment: Also tried:
String text = "<html>The quick <font color=#ffffdd>brown</font> fox.</html>"

Comment: `String t = "<html>The quick <font color=#A62A2A>brown</font> fox.";`
`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, t);`

This works for me...

Comment: omg finally got this to work. i'm sorry about all the trouble with it. I have a string that spans a few lines:
"asdfsdafasdf"+
"adfasfdsafdas."
Didn't realize the <html> tag had to start at the front of that line, not at the beginning of the para. That was the problem! Thanks so much for your continued help.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a `Component` to JOptionPane in the message parameter and will use that to display your message.

Something like a `JLabel` or a `JPanel` with labels on it.

**UPDATED**

JLabel, JPanel and HTML text examples

```
public class TestOptionPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello");
        label.setForeground(Color.RED);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        pnl.add(createLabel("The quick"));
        pnl.add(createLabel(" brown ", Color.ORANGE));
        pnl.add(createLabel(" fox "));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pnl);

        String text = "<html>The Quick <span style='color:green'>brown</span> fox</html>";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text);

    }

    public static JLabel createLabel(String text) {

        return createLabel(text, UIManager.getColor("Label.foreground"));

    }

    public static JLabel createLabel(String text, Color color) {

        JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        label.setForeground(color);

        return label;

    }

}
```

On the Mac-

[image: JOptionPane Example on Mac]

On Windows -

[image: JOptionPane example on Windows]

Comment: this doesn't appear to work either, the JOptionPane.showmessagedialog() seems to do a toString method to anything passed to the text field. So it actually shows the properties of the component not the component itself.

Comment: @whitewolfpgh I went back and expanded my test code, and it all seems to work fine for me...

Comment: Yes I was able to get yours to work as well. Thank you for putting all the info up. It looks like a "clean project" on eclipse fixed the problem ><