# How to make a red message in Swing JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I want to make my error messages red, which are made using Swing:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
 "Welcome\nTo\nJava\nProgramming!", "subject", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

But this code will show a dialog box with black message, what's the way to make it red?

Comment: on SO you can find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008100/formatting-text-in-jdialog-box) hope it helps you

Comment: Heck, isn't the big red icon *enough* red for you?  Worth noting that this deviates from the platform default for errors (usually), and that is rarely a good thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void showColoredMessageDialog(String message, Color color){
        //The label to show your message
        JLabel l = new JLabel(message);
        //the color for your message
        l.setForeground(color);
        //show JOptionPane.showMessageDialog with your custom color message
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, l);
    }

//You can call this method like for ex:
String msg = "hello world!";
//display this message with red color
showColoredMessageDialog(msg, Color.red);

//or you can also pass messages with variable values

int count = 10;
String msg2 = "the value of count is : " + count;

//display this message but this time with green color
showColoredMessageDialog(msg2, Color.green);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve it with help of HTML like next:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null ,
     "<html><div color=red>Welcome<br/>To<br/>Java<br/>Programming!" , "subject" , JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

[image: Red multi-line text in option pane]

Comment: but what if I don't have the variable exactly and it is just a var, I mean when it is like: String msg = "hello world", how can I make msg red, because when I use it in the html code above, msg will be shown instead of hello world.

Comment: you can use  "<html><div color=red>"+msg