# How to match the longest match in a regex using alternation?

Tags: java, html, regex, swing, jlabel

I develop in Java, and I'm trying to find a smart solution to properly set foreground color to JLabel even when using a multiline text using html.

I know that Swing has problems setting foreground to html text.
I thought to use regexes to discover if label's text is in html format, and if it is, adding to it a font tag.
The problem is that to make it properly work I have to call setText() at the end of the method. To avoid StackOverflowException, something has to be done.
So this is the regex I thought to:
    `<html>(<font [^>]*>)?((.*)(<\\/font><\\/html>)|(.*)<\\/html>)`

So, in my class overriding JLabel, I've overridden the method JLabel.getText():

```
@Override
public String getText()
  {
  String superText = super.getText();
  if (superText == null)
    return superText;
  Matcher m = pattern.matcher(superText);
  if (m.matches())
    {
    String text = "<html><font color=\""+retrieveHexColor()+"\">"+TempUtils.nvl(m.group(5), m.group(3))+"</font></html>";
    if (superText.equals(text))
      return superText;
    superText = text;
    }
  setText(superText);
  return superText;
  }
```

TempUtils.nvl is nothing more then

```
public static <T> T nvl(T value, T defaultValue)
  {
  return value == null ? defaultValue : value;
  }
```

I don't like this solution very much. Can you help me?
I thought that if I could just match the longest between `(<\\/font><\\/html>)` and `(.*)<\\/html>)` I easily solve my problem.

EDIT:
I've been asked some code to test what I'm saying:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    JLabel overriddenLabel = new JLabel("<html>aBc<br>deEEEF</html>", JLabel.CENTER) {

    Color foreground = Color.cyan;
        {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
            {
            foreground = Color.black;
            repaint();
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
            {
            foreground = Color.cyan;
            repaint();
            }
        });
        }
    @Override
        public Color getForeground()
            {
            return foreground;
            }

        };
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("AD");
    panel.add(overriddenLabel);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(300,300));
    }
```

As you can see, setting non-html text makes it properly work.

EDIT2: back from lunch. My solution is similar to this. And it works, but I don't like it.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    JLabel overriddenLabel = new JLabel("<html>aBc<br>deEEEF</html>", JLabel.CENTER) {

        Color foreground = Color.cyan;
            {
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
                {
                foreground = Color.black;
                repaint();
                }
                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
                {
                foreground = Color.cyan;
                repaint();
                }
            });
            }
        @Override
        public Color getForeground()
            {
            return foreground;
            }


        public String colorToHex(Color color)
            {
            if (color == null)
                return null;
            String hexColor = Integer.toHexString(color.getRGB() & 0xffffff);
            if (hexColor.length() < 6)
                hexColor = "000000".substring(0, 6 - hexColor.length()) + hexColor;
            return "#"+hexColor;
            }

        @Override
        public String getText()
            {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<html>(<font [^>]*>)?((.*)(<\\/font><\\/html>)|(.*)<\\/html>)");
            String superText = super.getText();
            if (superText == null)
                return superText;
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(superText);
            if (m.matches())
                {
                String text = "<html><font color=\""+colorToHex(foreground)+"\">"+(m.group(5) == null ? m.group(3) : m.group(5))+"</font></html>";
                if (superText.equals(text))
                    return superText;
                superText = text;
                }
            setText(superText);
            return superText;
            }

        };
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("AD");
    panel.add(overriddenLabel);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(300,300));
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to do that work in `getText`, it seems that it would make sense to do it in `setText`

Comment: *"I know that Swing has problems setting foreground to html text."* - Really, not sure I understand what you mean, seems to work okay [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008100/formatting-text-in-jdialog-box/12008603#12008603). Do you mean that the html overrides the foreground color property of the label?

Comment: @MadProgrammer in my case it doesn't work. I don't know what might be the problem. I've overridden getForeground too, maybe it create issues.
About your suggestion to put it in setText, I'm not sure it is correct: depending on some factors, among them the mouse position, foreground color changes. I don't think setText gets called when repainting the object

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problems (the coloring of the label as well as you attempted solution). This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks, I've udded some examples

Answer (score 1):

Workable solution without the need to jump about with regexp.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    JLabel overriddenLabel = new JLabel("<html>aBc<br>deEEEF</html>", JLabel.CENTER) {

        Color foreground = Color.cyan;

        {
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    setForeground(Color.black);
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    setForeground(Color.cyan);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    overriddenLabel.setForeground(Color.cyan);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("AD");
    panel.add(overriddenLabel);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
}
```

I don't know why you want to override `getForeground`, you're not doing anything special with it

Comment: I can't use something similar to this because every mouse event generate a change in the value of an enum. This change generates a change in foreground, background, and some different behaviour in the paintComponent method. Furthermore, my classe is overridden too, so it's easier to override JComponent's methods with behaviours depending on this enum. Thanks for your answer, though. I understand that the code I posted can't let you understand the real issue.

Comment: Okay, but observation is pretty simple, the problem is with your implementation and how use overridden yr methods, as this demonstrates that there is simply issue. Personally, I'd either use the MouseListener directly or have it call a method on your custom label to make decisions and change the state of the label as apposed to trying to do these things by overriding methods as that approach is obviously not working for you

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the correct regex for my problem. If somebody needs it, here it is:

`<html>(<[^>]*>)*(([^<]*)(<\/?br\/?>)?[^<]*)(<\/[^>]*>)*<\/html>`

Thanks.